# Nested async await function not executing in AWS Lambda Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, aws-lambda, async-await

Problem: I have very little experience working with async await functions and I am trying to execute a nested async await function within an if-else statement that depends on a higher level async function to execute upon an event detection. I expect to get a successful http response back from the nested async function, but I continue getting a null value for a response. The nested async function works as expected outside of the if-else statement, however. My goal is to simply be able to get the "await new Promise" part of the code to return a http response within the conditional if-else statement. Any help with this is appreciated.

What I've tried: I haven't really made any attempts to remedy the situation besides searching for questions with similar issues since I know very little about the nature of async await functions.

Code:

```
 exports.handler = async (event) => {
    
    const sensorId = event.sensorId;
    
    ddb.scan(params, function (err, data) {
  

    if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Success", data);
    console.log(typeof(data));
    data.Items.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
      console.log("printing", item);
      console.log('Testing', item.sensorId.S);
      
      if (item.sensorId.S == sensorId) {
          console.log('New sensorId was not created. Already Exists.');
          return ;
      }
      else {
    // Here is the nested async await function
    async () => {
    console.log(event.sensorId);
    const req = new AWS.HttpRequest(appsyncUrl, region);

    const item = {
        input: {
            id: event.sensorId,
            sensorId: event.sensorId
        }
    };

    req.method = "POST";
    req.path = "/graphql";
    req.headers.host = endpoint;
    req.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
    req.body = JSON.stringify({
        query: print(createSensor),
        operationName: "createSensor",
        variables: item
    });
    console.log(typeof(graphqlQuery));
    if (apiKey) {
        req.headers["x-api-key"] = apiKey;
    } else {
        const signer = new AWS.Signers.V4(req, "appsync", true);
        signer.addAuthorization(AWS.config.credentials, AWS.util.date.getDate());
    }
    
    
    const data =  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const httpRequest = https.request({ ...req, host: endpoint }, (result) => {
            let data = "";

            result.on("data", (chunk) => {
                data += chunk;
            });

            result.on("end", () => {
                resolve(JSON.parse(data.toString()));
            });
        });

        httpRequest.write(req.body);
        httpRequest.end();
    });
  
  


try {
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: data
    };
}

catch(err) {
    console.log('error', err);
}
      };
      
    }});
  }
});
```

Expected result:

```
Response
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": {
    "data": {
      "createSensor": {
        "id": "fd78597a-12fd-4bd1-9f9d-6ee1a88e197d",
        "digit": null,
        "date": null,
        "timestamp": null
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Actual result:

```
Response
null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. The nested async function — you're creating it but never executing it

```js
async () => { // creates an async anonymous arrow function, that's it

}
```

Two solutions:

```js
// wrapping the function in an IIFE create and executes it
(async () => {

})();

// give it a name and execute it later
async main() => {

}

main();
```

2. You can get rid of the nested async function by declaring the callback passed to forEach as async:

```js
data.Items.forEach(async (item, index, array) => { // <--- this is async
  // ...

  const req = new AWS.HttpRequest(appsyncUrl, region);
  const item = {
    input: {
      id: event.sensorId,
      sensorId: event.sensorId,
    },
  };

  // ...
});
```

3. The try/catch block at the end won't catch any errors. Instead, wrap the Promise you created inside a try/catch block and reject from inside upon an error event:

```js
try {
  const data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const httpRequest = https.request(
      { ...req, host: endpoint },
      (result) => {
        // ...

        result.on("error", (error) => {
          reject(error);
        });

        // ...
      }
    );

    // ...
  });

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: data,
  };
} catch (err) {
  console.log("error", err);
}
```

4. Running async operations inside forEach does not do what you intend to do. You probably intend to respond *after* all sensorsIds have been created. What really happens is that you respond as soon as the first sensorId is created. That's because forEach fires the callbacks for `data.Items` simultaneously. A solution for this is to use map instead and return an array of Promises which you can then await with Promise.all.

Here's the final code and how I would solve it. As an extra I've promisified `ddb.scan` so you're not mixing callbacks with promises and async/await:

```js
const scanAsync = util.promisify(ddb.scan);

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const sensorId = event.sensorId;

  try {
    const data = await scanAsync(params);

    const responses = await Promise.all(
      data.Items.map((item) => {
        if (item.sensorId.S == sensorId) {
          console.log("New sensorId was not created. Already Exists.");
          return;
        }

        const req = new AWS.HttpRequest(appsyncUrl, region);
        const item = {
          input: {
            id: event.sensorId,
            sensorId: event.sensorId,
          },
        };

        req.method = "POST";
        req.path = "/graphql";
        req.headers.host = endpoint;
        req.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
        req.body = JSON.stringify({
          query: print(createSensor),
          operationName: "createSensor",
          variables: item,
        });

        if (apiKey) {
          req.headers["x-api-key"] = apiKey;
        } else {
          const signer = new AWS.Signers.V4(req, "appsync", true);
          signer.addAuthorization(
            AWS.config.credentials,
            AWS.util.date.getDate()
          );
        }

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const httpRequest = https.request(
            { ...req, host: endpoint },
            (result) => {
              let data = "";

              result.on("data", (chunk) => {
                data += chunk;
              });

              result.on("error", (error) => {
                reject(error);
              });

              result.on("end", () => {
                resolve(JSON.parse(data.toString()));
              });
            }
          );

          httpRequest.write(req.body);
          httpRequest.end();
        });
      })
    );

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: responses,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error);
  }
};
```

I hope you learned a thing or two from my response :). Let me know if you have any questions.